# Change opacity of style icon's in the openlayer maps in Angular 16+

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

I need to change the style icons in the Feature added to the openlayers map (using latest openlayers version). I am using single layer only so I cannot apply the opacity in the layer. I have multiple points plotted with different coordinates with icons and now I need to change the opacity of the icons other than the selected feature.

Below is my function to assign the style icon in map layer.

```
const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
if (geometry && geometry.getType() === 'Point') {
return new Style({
      image: new Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        src: `./assets/icons/ic-${feature.values_.status}.img`,
      }),
    });
}
```

With the select interaction I want to reduce the opacity of the other icons expect selected.

here is my select event handler from map.

```
this.map.addInteraction(this.select);
this.select.on('select', function (e) {
if(e.selected.length) {
 const selectmark = e.selected as Feature[];
 mymaplayer.setStyle(feature=> {
   console.log(feature);
 });
}
```

I planned to get the style from layer and to update it but I couldn't perform it. Also tried to set the style using setStyle function but couldn't achieve it as well.
Any simpler way to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Select interaction with null style, a vector layer with a style function which checks if any features are selected, and if they include the one being styled.  Fire a change on the layer when the selection is changed.

```
const select = new Select({style: null});

const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: function (feature) {
    const selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures().getArray();
    const opacity =
      selectedFeatures.length === 0 || selectedFeatures.includes(feature)
        ? 1
        : 0.5;
    iconStyle.getImage().setOpacity(opacity);
    return iconStyle;
  },
});

select.on('select', function () {
  vectorLayer.changed();
});
```

Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-color-forked-7vx7j2?file=/main.js

Comment: is there a way I can add a black circle (using stroke) around the icon like your sample by using the style object itself?

Comment: Use an array of two styles, one with `ol/style/Circle` and one with `ol/style/Icon`

Comment: @Mike..In your working example you have four point feature, can we show the points one by one in animation with some time interval? How can I achieve such rendering?